# Sort Array of Objects by property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Example',
    slug: 'example'
    },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Homepage',
    slug: 'homepage'
  }
]
```

I am trying to sort the above array so the object containing `slug: 'homepage'`, I have looked into using sort function but have only managed to sort alphabetically.

Comment: It's unclear, do you want to sort or filter?

Comment: Sort, keeping all properties just with homepage always at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind about the order, except that the homepages must appear first, then something like this would work:

```js
const categories = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Example',
    slug: 'example'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Homepage',
    slug: 'homepage'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Homepage2',
    slug: 'homepage'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'other',
    slug: 'other'
  }
];

const sorted = categories.sort(({ slug }) => slug === 'homepage' ? -1 : 0);

console.log(sorted);
```